# two modules for WM8962

Tags: linux, kernel, embedded, module, codec

As can be seen on https://www.kernelconfig.io/search?q=wm8962&kernelversion=4.19.165&arch=arm64 there are seemingly two different kernel modules for the audio codec WM8962 and they have entirely different dependencies as well. Is there a good way to determine which one should be utilized? I understand that one of them is for i.MX boards but what exactly is the difference? Does one need to dive into the code to find out about the variations?